# Entity Framework DB First Identity Column override?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, frameworks, entity, ef-database-first

I have a MVC-Project with a DB-First EDMX file from a production database.
Let's say table Person has an identity-column named ID.
I also have a copy of this database where I have turnd OFF the Identity-Option for the ID column. My goal is to synchronize data between these two databases.
To connect to each of these databases I use the same context-class with different connection-strings.
The problem with this is, that when I try to add a copy of a row from table Person from productionDB to my copyDB I get an error, because EntityFramework is trying to insert NULL for the ID column. I know that this is totally normal, because the EDMX-File has set identity to TRUE for the ID-column of table Person, but is there a way to programatically change this behaviour?

```
Context prod = new Context("ProductionConnectionString");
Context prodCopy = new Context("CopyConnectionString");

var prodEntity = prod.Person.First(); \\ RETURNS A PERSON WITH ID 1
prodCopy.Person.Add(prodEntity):
prodCopy.SaveChanges(); \\THIS WILL THROW AN EXCEPTION BECAUSE EF WILL REPLACE 1 WITH NULL BECAUSE IDENTITY OPTION
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `prod.Person` is different than `prodCopy.Person` right? Their structure might be the same and might contain the same fields/properties but they should be in different namespaces. How could you add a `prodEntity` into a `prodCopy` person list? You might need to new up a `prodCopy.Person` and copy `prod.Person` over (minus the ID value). You can 
 also implement the prototype pattern which helps you define a pattern to clone objects but I am not sure if it's possible with database-first.

Comment: @DavidLiang Prod.Person and Copy.Person are identical except that Copy.Person has no auto-increment identity column so that I am able to copy the PrimaryKey from Prod.Person to Copy.Person. Because I use the same Context-Class created by the EDMX-Flie it is no problem to pull an object from prod and add it to copy except for the ID-column, because it is an auto-increment identity in prod but not in copy. I just need a way to tell EntityFramework to not treat the ID-Column as Identity when I call SaveChanges(). So it does not replace the ID I copied from prodPerson to copyPerson with null.

Comment: Oh ok I got it now. Have you tried just turning off the Identity Specification of the ID column in your copyDB and refreshing the edmx?

Comment: @DavidLiang Sorry, I think I still did not explain it correctly. There is only one EDMX File that was generated from the production database. So this one contains the identity for the ID column. To get a Prod.Person I create an Object of the EDMX created contextClass with the ProdDB-Connection-String. To get a Copy.Person I create another Object of the EDMX created contextClass with the CopyDB-Connection-String. Like I show in my first post. So the EDMX is supposed to contain the identity for the ID column but I would like to temporarily deactivate it when saving a Person to the CopyDB.